# Given a VcPkg port SHA512 hash, how do I find that commit?

Tags: git, github, vcpkg

Given the SHA512, of say, boost type_trait:

SHA512: 83d585933374420808aaf3743cda48d914bb7d536bf3f19e59bba1b24403a1482ff509e1f804a0b55d3bc434aceedcb0b75f873b9feaa9ba1c1a762a11d4fc94

as seen in the portfile.cmake, here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/commit/0e759709ddc7dbad0b881f9f068f1b04b2092773#diff-d98fb13ff562baedc0c0ebbc756bf761

Is there any way to find out when that commit was made? I tried git log, but it does not work since the git commits are SHA1.

Thank you.

Comment: Nothing built into git, no. You will need to re-hash every object in the git repository, depending on what the hash is for, and then compare.

Comment: You can't. That's why it would be good that the commit hash be included, more and more, in the version like it is permitted by semantic versioning : https://semver.org/#spec-item-10